# Mobx observable update not render update

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I had a problem with react and mobx. Updating my observable attributes did not cause the render of my component.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you split this up into a question and an answer, and add the answer below? It is not standard Stack Overflow practice to put the answer in the question like this.

Comment: ok, sorry, i split

Answer (score 1):

After multiple search, I finally found the problem on the side of my Babel plugin.
I had put

```
"plugins": ["transform-class-properties","transform-decorators-legacy"]
```

instead of

```
"plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
```

if you have the same problem check the order of your babel plugins ;)